# Hide a Travis repository

Tags: github, travis-ci

I am part of a Github organization, but there are some projects in that organization which I don't work on and whose tests are always failing. Is there a way to make it so I don't have to see them? It clutters my sidebar and I can't seem to find a way to hide those projects, at least not without disabling them (which is very heavy-handed, not applicable to this case, and I can't even do because I don't have admin rights to some of the repos).

Answer (score 2):

There's a relevant [feature request](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/5258). It's been open since Dec '09 though.